# Requesting Permission to Retag [enterprise-architect] Questions

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

There are 96 questions on [so] tagged with the [enterprise-architect](/questions/tagged/enterprise-architect) tag. Most of these are about the Sparx Enterprise Architect product.

Today, for the first time, I noticed an [enterprise-architect](/questions/tagged/enterprise-architect) question which is not about the Sparx product (at least I think not, the question needs clarification). This tells me that at least some people are using that tag for the "other" purpose listed in the tag wiki:

> Enterprise Architect can refer to the UML modeling tool created by
>   Sparx Systems (http://sparxsystems.com.au/) or to the specialized
>   architect role. In order to specify the tool as meaning, add the tag
>   [sparx] in addition.

Now, as it happens, there is no [sparx](/questions/tagged/sparx) tag.

I would like to create the tag [sparx-enterprise-architect](/questions/tagged/sparx-enterprise-architect), or maybe [sparx-ea](/questions/tagged/sparx-ea), and I'd like to *add* that new tag to those [enterprise-architect](/questions/tagged/enterprise-architect) questions which are actually about the Sparx product.

Any comments?

---

BTW, I'm asking because I was once threatened with suspension for adding the [c#-language](/questions/tagged/c%23-language) tag without permission from the community here on meta.

---

Here are the questions which are *not* about Sparx EA:

- [WebSphere Equivalent in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009836/websphere-equivalent-in-net)
- [A good ADL recomendation for a web based system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416590/a-good-adl-recomendation-for-a-web-based-system)
- [How to design application for multi-branches POS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461149/how-to-design-application-for-multi-branches-pos)
- [Enterprise architecture certifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231598/enterprise-architecture-certifications)
- [What reporting tool do you suggest for an enterprise level ASP.Net MVC application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058902/what-reporting-tool-do-you-suggest-for-an-enterprise-level-asp-net-mvc-applicati)
- [Best approaches to reduce the number of searches between the object stores to find a document if we are concerned about time of the document creation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952554/best-approaches-to-reduce-the-number-of-searches-between-the-object-stores-to-fi)

Comment: [c#-language] is just bad because there is already a [c#] tag. Now to your question: have you prove the tag is used for other things rather than the `sparx` thing? If not I don't see any meaning in retagging. If the tag is used for multiple things it would be useful to retag. As long as you don;t use the [sparx-ea] tag. Of the 96 questions how is it devided between the 2 meanings?

Comment: If there are only six questions mis-using the tag, just remove that tag from them. Edit the wiki to only talk about the Sparx thing, and all should be good.

Comment: What tag would people use to discuss Enterprise Architecture? Should I create an enterprise-architecture tag?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Those questions are either not constructive, not a real question or just off topic IMHO.